# Update case and opportunity owner to login user using custom button

Tags: custom-button, opportunity, case, ownership

Update case and opportunity owner to login user using custom button:

I am having a case record 'x' and i want to create a custom button and when i click the button it will update case owner and opportunity owner to login user. How can i achieve this??

Comment: Are you here referring the custom detail page or list button or button in VF page?

Comment: I tried in calling a apex class using onclick javascript button but i am new to it i am not able to call apex class

Comment: @ase I think this is what you are looking for. just update the relevant fields accordingly. https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000ggpwAAA

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create any apex class for accomplishing this.
You can make use of connection.js file. Place following code on click of javascript

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 
var objCase= new sforce.SObject("Case"); 
objCase.Id = '{!Case.Id}';
objCase.OwnerId = '{!$User.Id}';
var result = sforce.connection.update([objCase]);
```

Repeat same for Opportunity object and replace Case with Opportunity.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It is working fine. how can i update case related opportunitites and i am having few custom objects owner to update???

Comment: Are you referring here that Opportunity object has a lookup with Case i.e. Opportunity is the child object of Case?

Comment: For other custom objects, you can simply replace the Case with Custom object API name in the code shared.

{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 
var objCase= new sforce.SObject(custom object API name); 
objCase.Id = '{!customobject.Id}';
objCase.OwnerId = '{!$User.Id}';
var result = sforce.connection.update([objCase]);

Comment: Yes @ pankaj  . In case i am having lookup to opportunity. If i click on the button it must update case owner, opportunity owner, an custom object owner with one button click

Answer (score 0):

Hi Pankaj i have written the code for opportunity

var objCase= new sforce.SObject(opportunity); 
objCase.Id = '{!opportunityId}'; 
objCase.OwnerId = '{!$User.Id}'; 
var result = sforce.connection.update([objCase]);

var result = sforce.connection.update([objCase]);

But i am getting error for this please help me out it is a lookup field

Comment: {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 
var objCase= new sforce.SObject("Opportunity"); 
objCase.Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}';
objCase.OwnerId = '{!$User.Id}';
var result = sforce.connection.update([objCase]);

Comment: Case is working fine but for oppportunity case owner remains same. Button is on case object may be it is not calling related opportunity??

Comment: Or can u please help me out how to call apex class from javascript also helps me. Please guide me

Comment: Please check my below response.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}



    var result = sforce.apex.execute("ClassName","methodName",
    {sId:"{!Object.Id}",
    sName:"{!Object.Name}"});
    alert(result);
```

Controller:

```
global class ClassName
{

    webservice static String methodName(Id sId, String sName)
    {

}
   }
```